# How can I make functions available to other javascript files?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

$(document).ready(function () {

```
function loginLinkClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#loginLink').unbind('click', loginLinkClick);
    dialog(this);
}
function registerLinkClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#registerLink').unbind('click', registerLinkClick);
    dialog(this);
}

$('#loginLink')
    .bind('click', loginLinkClick);
$('#registerLink')
    .bind('click', registerLinkClick);
$('#logoutLink')
    .click(function (e) {
        window.location = $(this).attr('data-href')
    });
```

});

I want to have my loginLinkClick and registerLinkClick functions available to other javascript files. Is there a way that I can do this? I'm using jQuery so should I put them into the jQuery namespace or something like that?

One more question. From a performance point of view or for maintainability should I have functions like these outside of the $(document)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the functions available outside of that scope, instead of

```
function loginLinkClick(e) { }
```

try adding them to the window object with

```
window.loginLinkClick = function(e) { }
```

Comment: Will it be okay as these functions reference .unbind for some elements that might not yet be created.

Comment: The functions are not being executed, only defined. The difference is the scope from which they can be called.

Answer (score 2):

Remove them from the local namespace and import this file before the "other javascript files" and the functions will be available to them.

Quoting Torok Gabor from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645344/functions-inside-or-outside-jquery-document-ready):

> Put it inside so it won't pollute the global namespace. It also ensures a faster resolve of the function name because of JavaScript's scope chains.
>
> Put it outside if it's a reusable component so you could easily move it in a separate file and call from different contexts.

Answer (score 2):

Either add the function's to the `window` object or move them out of the local `function` scope.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    window.loginLinkClick = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#loginLink').unbind('click', loginLinkClick);
        dialog(this);
    };
});
```

Or:

```
function loginLinkClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#loginLink').unbind('click', loginLinkClick);
    dialog(this);
};

$(document).ready(function () { ... });
```

Comment: So I could just move them before document ready and that would be all that is needed?

Comment: @SamanthaJ right, given the `document.ready` bit is not itself inside another function...

Comment: If I put the functions before will they still work okay if for example the #loginLink has not been created? I'm asking this because the functions have inside of them a line that adds unbind to some links.

Comment: yes, it'll work. the function's won't get called until their associated events occur ...