# Unable to call a function within a js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, call

My index.php has the following lines:

```
<!doctype html><html class=""><head><title>a title</title>
<link href="_css/boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="_script/popup.js"></script>
```

.... then we get too:

```
<?php
if(isset ($_GET['page']))
  {
    if ($_GET['page'] == "mail")
      {
         echo "<script>window.alert('Found the reply!');var formPosted = true;</script>";
   }
   }
?>
<script>
if(formPosted) {
  window.alert("popupclick!");
  popupClick();
}
</script>
```

the alert popupclick! displays on the screen however the function popupClick() doesn't seem to  work.

popup.js (which has the function popupClick() in:

```
jQuery(function($) {

$("a.topopup").click(function() {
        loading(); // loading
        setTimeout(function(){ // then show popup, deley in .5 second
            loadPopup(); // function show popup 
        }, 500); // .5 second
return false;
});

/* event for close the popup */
$("div.close").hover(
                function() {
                    $('span.ecs_tooltip').show();
                },
                function () {
                    $('span.ecs_tooltip').hide();
                }
            );

$("div.close").click(function() {
    disablePopup();  // function close pop up
});

$(this).keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 27) { // 27 is 'Ecs' in the keyboard
        disablePopup();  // function close pop up
    }   
});

$("div#backgroundPopup").click(function() {
    disablePopup();  // function close pop up
});

 /************** start: functions. **************/
function popupClick() {
    window.alert("insidePopupClick!!!!");
    loading(); // loading
    setTimeout(function(){ // then show popup, deley in .5 second
        loadPopup(); // function show popup 
    }, 500); // .5 second
}

function loading() {
    $("div.loader").show();  
}
function closeloading() {
    $("div.loader").fadeOut('normal');  
}

var popupStatus = 0; // set value

function loadPopup() { 
    if(popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
        closeloading(); // fadeout loading
        $("#toPopup").fadeIn(0500); // fadein popup div
        $("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity", "0.7"); // css opacity, supports IE7, IE8
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn(0001); 
        popupStatus = 1; // and set value to 1
    }   
}

function disablePopup() {
    if(popupStatus == 1) { // if value is 1, close popup
        $("#toPopup").fadeOut("normal");  
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("normal");  
        popupStatus = 0;  // and set value to 0
    }
}
/************** end: functions. **************/
}); // jQuery End
```

Thank you for helping!  Chris

Comment: your function isn't available globally, therefore you can't use it globally. You can only use it within the scope that you defined it in. `window.popupClick = popupClick` should expose the function to the global scope.

Comment: possible duplicate of [functions inside or outside jquery document ready](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645344/functions-inside-or-outside-jquery-document-ready)

Comment: There are no duplicates of that function popupClick() anywhere else.  To be honest I'm a little confused, I tinkered with Java's scopes for variables and methods.  I didn't realise JS even had scope.  How would I make the function popupClick() public?

Comment: `window.popupClick = popupClick` would make it global. the *"possible duplicate" comment suggests another question that is somewhat similar to this one that has an answer that also answers this one.

Comment: Apologies Kevin, I'm not very good and a little brain fried tonight.  I don't really understand the other post.

Comment: I understand that I need to make my function onClick() global.  The line above onclick I put window.popupClick = popupClick(); but I'm not sure how to call it from the index.php and the things I'm looking at are as clear as mud to a beginner talking abour wrappers

Comment: window.popupClick = function(){
  //window.alert("insidePopupClick!!!!");
        loading(); // loading
        setTimeout(function(){ // then show popup, deley in .5 second
            loadPopup(); // function show popup 
        }, 500); // .5 second
 }

Comment: I literally meant adding a single line of code, after your `popupClick` function definition. you didn't have to reorganize your code or change any of the existing code.

Answer (score 0):

With the following syntax:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    ...
});
```

the code between curly-braces is executed only after the entire page has been loaded, so the function `popupClick` is not yet defined when you call it.
You should extract the function definitions from the closure:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    ...
}); // jQuery End

/************** start: functions. **************/
...
/************** end: functions. **************/
```