# Table row highlight does not work on dynamic rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to dynamically add rows using jquery and attach mouse events to highlight the row.   It works when i add the row the first time, but on subsequent row additions, the highlight on the previous row stop working.

Here is the fiddle:
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobm76/2pnjshL0/7/)

HTML

```
<table border=1 id="testTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>            
</table>
<input type="submit" id="add" value="Add"/>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $("#add").on('click',function(){
        console.log("Add clicked");
        $('<tr>').append(
            $('<td>').text('Val1'),
            $('<td>').text('Val2'),
            $('<td>').text('Val3')
            ).appendTo('#testTable');
        highlight('testTable');
    });
    function highlight(tableid){
        var row = tableid+" tbody tr";
        $("#"+row).on('mouseover mouseout', (function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
        }
                                            ))}                                             

});
```

css

```
tr.highlight td{background: #B0C4DE}
```

Comment: Why not just use a plain CSS solution for the highlighting? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/o4Laoxxz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.off()` before attaching the mouse events as you are binding the events multiple times and that is causing the hover issue for you. The best fix would be to only attach the events once so that you wont have to unbind the events everytime.

```
$("#"+row).off().on('mouseover mouseout', (function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
});
```

Hope that helps

http://jsfiddle.net/2pnjshL0/9/

Comment: Note that .unbind() just calls .off() as of jQuery 1.7

Answer (score 5):

No need to add event to each row explicitly.

```
$("#testTable tbody").on('mouseover mouseout', 'tr', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
});
```

This will add the events to all `tr`s even to the dynamically appended.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/2pnjshL0/11/

Comment: I'm trying to create a generic function for the highlight and i tried to tweak the code to something similar to the solution you highlighted, but the highlight is completely lost for the even clicks (second, fourth click, etc).

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/2pnjshL0/10/

```
$(function() {
    $("#add").on('click', function() {
        console.log("Add clicked");
        $('<tr>').append(
            $('<td>').text('Val1'),
            $('<td>').text('Val2'),
            $('<td>').text('Val3')
        ).appendTo('#testTable');
        highlight('testTable');
    });

    function highlight(tableid) {
        var row = tableid + " tbody";
        $("#" + row).on('mouseover mouseout', 'tr', (function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
        }))
    }

});
```

Comment: @Tushar: I totally disagree with you, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645344/functions-inside-or-outside-jquery-document-ready Its all depend on case

Answer (score 0):

Change the function for applying the highlight to:

```
function highlight(tableid){
    $("#testTable tbody :last-child").on('mouseover mouseout', function(){
         $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    })
}
```

This will only apply the event to the last child element in tbody after each row is added.  Making it more efficient than unbinding everything to rebind it again.

Comment: Since the highlight function is a generic one that gets used across the application, there are scenarios where more than one row could be added at the same time.