# What must be declare or input inside the $(document).ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript so I make this thread. I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645344/functions-inside-or-outside-jquery-document-ready) some post. In this post is the function `inside or outside` of the document ready. If it is declare outside the document can I re-use / call it in another JScript?.

As my title what should be the contain inside of a document ready?.

Comment: Every function which changes something on the view like an animation or something should be in the `$(document).ready()` function

Comment: @DestinatioN sorry for being new. Can you give me an example of `Change Something` even its very simple.

Comment: @DestinatioN – It depends... I have never used `$(document).ready()` since last 4 years...

Comment: did my answer help... do you mind marking it as answered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(document).ready` is an event which fires up when document is ready.

Suppose you have placed your jQuery code in head section and trying to access a dom element (an anchor, an img etc), you will not be able to access it because html is interpreted from top to bottom and your html elements are not present when your jQuery code runs.

To overcome this problem, we place every jQuery/javascript code (which uses DOM) inside `$(document).ready` function which gets called when all the dom elements can be accessed.

If you place your jQuery code at the bottom (after all dom elements, just before ) , there is no need for `$(document).ready`

See the example, which `alert` calls first that will give you an idea what should be inside the `ready`.

```js
alert("Without Ready");

$(document).ready(function(){
  alert("With Ready");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As I notice when loading the 1st alert prompt and after the load 2nd prompt

Comment: Yes, That's the difference, which should be outside the ready and inside the ready.

Comment: For example I have a function of a button click what will be the difference if I put it `Inside / Outside?`

Comment: I would personally prefer to use ready function, because it will wait till your DOM is ready. But you can use $('button').click event inside the ready and outside as well.

Comment: I see.. lastly I have a grid that I want to show in first load where should I call it outside or inside?.

Comment: What do you mean by first load ? There is function window unload also, you can check that also.

Comment: First load. I think it is inside the document because after the page load the grid data will load also

Comment: If you want to call any function / event on a DOM element, I would suggest to wait till the DOM element is ready, for that you should use ready event.

Comment: if your not busy now can you make a chat room? because It suggested already to move to discussion. I don't know how to make a chat room.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124184/discussion-between-loading-and-je-cca).

Answer (score 4):

`.ready` makes sure your DOM is ready and good to go for binding, so putting all your functions inside there like the events functions would only be bootstrap at ready state of the document. Normal functions( with name i.e non anonymous functions) can be declared outside the `document.ready` so you can re-use it somewhere else. since those functions are called from the `document.ready` events or jquery code to be used.

See more about document.ready [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). check the snippet below for a brief example layouting

```js
/**
Global function here, which is not called or bind on page load
*/

function alertWindow(message){
  alert ("Window is loaded here with Message: "+message);
  $("#console").text(message);
  }

$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#showBtn").click(function(event){
    var ourMessage = $("#message").val();
    alertWindow(ourMessage);
    });
  
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Enter Message" >
<br>
<button id="showBtn">Show Message</button>

<p>
  <h3>Console Here</h3>
<div id="console"></div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

when we use document.ready all the listeners and all the functions inside the document ready will work only after the page load completed.
So for example if you added any listener to a button and that perform some change in your page then better to write it inside the document.ready.

Comment: Do you mean in add listener in button is something like saving of data?

Comment: yeah that is one of the cases

Comment: What will happen if a put it outside?

Answer (score 3):

First things first - In JavaScript a function defines the scope of the code it contains, so if you want to share it you need to define it in a location that your other code can see.

You also don't need to define functions inside the document ready function, you could just define outside of the ready() callback. Eg,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        somefunc();
    });
});

function somefunc()
{
     alert('yes');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   // do something else
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this help..

Comment: Your example is not working :). Inside or Outside of the ready is fine right?. What is `callback?`.

Comment: its not a example -  I am showing how you can write and call function inside document.ready() on click of a button- somefunc() is defined outside.

Comment: nothing - I as said earlier it just a sample -  code.. the second document.ready() ignore -  i am showing that it can  be used for another code..  See document.ready() confirms that the page is ready and any code included inside document. ready()once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute, so you can write $(document).ready() or $function(){ })

Answer (score 2):

The ready event occurs when the DOM (document object model) has been loaded.
Because this event occurs after the document is ready, it is a good place to have all other jQuery events and functions. Like in the example above.
source : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_ready.asp

For example: if DOM is not fully loaded and our JS code is trying to access unloaded DOM. We will get Javascript error. To avoid this we need to give some time for loading document. To achieve this, We have a callback function for DOM loaded `$(document).ready()` or `$(function)`

We can have functions out side ready and those we can access for other JS also. It is always better to write Jquery add event and other Jquery related code inside ready method.

Comment: As I understand if I have a function inside the document it will not be functioning if the DOM is not finish loaded right?. If i have function outside the document if DOM finish or not the function be trigger?

Comment: @jEccA Correct you can see same example in accepted answer. And answer to "it will not be functioning if the DOM is not finish loaded" may be if any dependence of unloaded DOM object.

Answer (score 2):

Refers from [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/):

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready."
>   jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside
>   `$(document).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object
>   Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included
>   inside `$(window ).load(function() { ... })` will run once the entire
>   page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

Since usually we've used jQuery to selecting and/or manipulating the DOM, so the best way to that is after the DOM is fully loaded. For those reason, so we need an event to watch the DOM *ready* state. This method give us flexibility where we'll write our javascript code, either on `<head>` nor at the end of `<body>`.

See my snippet samples below:

---

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      // this will not work properly
      $('div').html('Hello World!!!');
    </script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div>Hi brother!!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

> Above script will not work properly since the script was executed
>   before the DOM loaded properly. So, the jquery can not find the
>   element with `div` tag.
>
> To make the script running smooth, we need to add additional event listener from jquery named `$(document).ready()` as you can see at snippet below.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      // this will work properly
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('div').html('Hello World!!!');
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div>Hi brother!!!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

But, how if we don't want to add `ready` method? We still can do that, if we write the script below required DOM, see below snippet for example:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div></div>
    
    <script>
      // this will not work properly
      $('div').html('Hello World!!!');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**UPDATE :**
Refers from OP comment below:

> In your reference I read use the shorthand `$()` for `$( document
>   ).ready()` so I can use like `$()` for `document.ready`?

YES, you can use that shorthand, see my snippet below:

```html
<html>
      <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          // this will work properly
          $(function() {
            $('div').html('Hello World!!!');
          });
        </script>
      </head>
      
      <body>
        <div>Hi brother!!!</div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: In your reference I read `use the shorthand $() for $( document ).ready()` so I can use like `$()` for document.ready?

Comment: Thanks for the infos I will try to use `$()` instead of $(document).ready().. If i use `$()` what will be the end? for the document ready is `$(document).ready(function(){});` right?.

Comment: I am feel unclear for your statement (If i use $() what will be the end?).. perhaps i am not wrong: If you use `$()` you still need to add `function` keyword, so the jquery know what the procedure inside it that will be execute `$(function() { ...put your script here... });`. As you can see at my snippet above

Comment: Ow it still the same.. Sorry hard speak in english.. not my language still learning to it.