# Using Jquery Descendent Selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to change the background color of a textbox in a form using Jquery descendant selector on this page [jQuery Descendant code](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

Here's the form code I am using.

```
<form><div>Picnic Sign Up Form</div><label for="name">Full name</label>
<input name="fullname" id="fullname">
<fieldset>
<label for="firstname">Firstname here</label>
<input name="firstname" id="firstname"/> 
<label for="lastname">Lastname here</label>
<input name="lastname" id="lastname"/></fieldset></form>
$( "form fieldset input" ).css( "backgroundColor", "yellow" );
```

When I do this, it doesn't turn the inputs in the fieldset yellow. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Can't see if they've been added already by your code above but if not:

Scripts need to be in  tags

Also the css for background colour is: background-color

```
<script>
    $( "form fieldset input" ).css( "background-color", "yellow" );
</script>
```

And as you are using Jquery, you will need to include the jquery library before your script.

Comment: I was able to figure out what I did wrong. The css for backgroundColor is suppose to be background-color.  Also, I put my code in the document.ready function. It worked when I did this but not when it was outside this function.  This is mentioned as a best practice on the jQuery website. It says you have to do this to ensure that the jQuery code activates after the page is fully loaded.  There is more on this at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645344/functions-inside-or-outside-jquery-document-ready & http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works