# How to close the navigation bar by clicking outside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I have a Drupal 8.6.8 site with Bootstrap 3.3.7 theme

I want my navigation menu to close when I click outside. I tried with the code :

```
(function ($) {
  'use strict';

  $(document).click(function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest('#navbar-collapse-first').length) {
      $('.navbar-collapse-first').collapse('hide');
    }
  });

  $(document).click(function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest('#navbar-collapse-second').length) {
      $('.navbar-collapse-second').collapse('hide');
    }
  });

}(jQuery));
```

https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/

It does not work, if I click outside the navigation menu, it does not This code only works if I delete the second one or leave the second one and delete the first one.

How to apply this on the 2 menu ?

**UPDATE :**

I found the answer :

```
(function ($) {
  'use strict';

  $(document).click(function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest('#navbar-collapse-first').length) {
      $('.navbar-collapse-first').collapse('hide');
    }
    if (!$(event.target).closest('#navbar-collapse-second').length) {
      $('.navbar-collapse-second').collapse('hide');
    }
  });

}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use This function

```
function OnwindowClick(elem , action){
    $(document).on('click',function(e){
        if (!$(elem).is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
            && $(elem).has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        {
            action();
        }
    });
}
```

and use it like

```
// OnwindowClick(elem , action) add the prevent elements in `elem` something like this
OnwindowClick('#navbar-collapse-first , #navbar-collapse-second', function(){
   $('.navbar-collapse-first, .navbar-collapse-second').collapse('hide');
});
```

**Notes:**

- No need to use `.closest()` use the selector directly
- `elem` are the elements to prevent the document click on it

**Additional:** You still need to add the buttons to the `elem` .. `#navbar-collapse-first , #navbar-collapse-second , button1_Selector , button2_Selector`

**Example** of how to use this function

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button.clickable').on('click' , function(){
    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Like' ? 'Dislike' : 'Like');
  });
  
  OnwindowClick('button.clickable' , function(){
    $('button.clickable').fadeOut(400);
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('button.clickable').fadeIn(400);
    } , 5000);
  });
});


function OnwindowClick(elem , action){
    $(document).on('click',function(e){
        if (!$(elem).is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
            && $(elem).has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        {
            action();
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="clickable">Like</button>
```

Comment: Hello, putting the logic in it's own function is a great approach. `function OnwindowClick(elem, action)` could also go inside the `$(document).ready(function(){})`. Is their a specific reason to put it outside ?

Comment: @LebCit You can use it anywhere you want while its working .. but since it's inside the ready function, it isn't being defined until after the whole DOM has been parsed .. You can take a look at [functions inside or outside jquery document ready](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2645353/3385827)

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried this:

```
    $(document).click(function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest('#navbar-collapse-second, #navbar-collapse-second').length) {
      $('.navbar-collapse-second, .navbar-collapse-second').collapse('hide');
    }
  });
```